# Connect to MySQL from remote machine

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a problem connecting to my MySQL server running on a linux machine.
It works fine from the local network (any computer in the same network).

Anyway, no connection can be established from other networks.

I have no idea why..

In the my.cnf I've set the `port=3306` and `bind-address=0.0.0.0`.

```
netstat -an | grep 3306
returns    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The MySQL user is created like this

```
create user 'user'@'%' identified by 'pass';
create user 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';

grant select on *.* to 'user'@'%';
grant select on *.* to 'user'@'localhost';
```

A portforwarding for port 3306 is configured in the router.

The file hosts.deny is empty.

As far as I can tell my server is listening on 3306 and nobody is between it and any client who blocks, still nobody but local clients can connect.

I've tried many solutions I found on stackoverflow but none of them helped..

I also have to admit I'm not that much used to Linux, so please give "noob-instructions" :)

Comment: If you say other networks, are you on a private network, and the other networks are somewhere on internet? because in that case you will have to port forward mysql's port on your internet router.

Comment: have you tried verifying whether your server is reachable on port 3306? If you can, stop MySQL on that port, and run `nc -l 3306` on the server. From the client connecting from outside your LAN, run `nc yourServerIP 3306`, type something and hit enter. If you can see what you typed on the server, the network configuration is ok.

Comment: yes, it's another network over the internet.
Anyway, the port is actually already forwarded on the router.

Comment: @micheleb Only my server runs on linux, is there any way I can do this with a windows machine?

Comment: you can replace `nc` with `telnet` on windows

Comment: That doesn't work. I receive "Connecting to example.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed" at the client

Comment: have u try this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql`

Comment: @Asad yes, I've tried this one as well, no success :(

Comment: you need to replace `example.com` with the actual IP of your server :)

Comment: Still not working. Anyway, domain works with other ports ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many "try and error"-approaches I figuered it out, I had to comment out the line "skip-external-locking" in the mysql config file.

I hope this might help someone having the same problem :)